# Use CSS3 Filter to change specific color

Tags: css, filter, colors, rgb

Currently I have an a `.png`-image consisting only of the two colors white (`#FFFFFF`) and a reddish color (`#EA3D05`) and I'd like to change the color of this image using CSS filters. In particular I need to replace the white color with black (`#000000`) and keep the red color as is.

My current approach is to use

```
filter: invert(100%);
```

This will use the color the white pixels black, but affects the red color as well. I thought that now it would be possible to change the (now blue pixels) back to red (`#EA3D05`), since the other pixels are black. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I need it for my user styles (creating my own dark themes for websites that doesn't have them), since I have no control of the image source.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider the use of `filter` and `mix-blend-mode` to approximate this:

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: radial-gradient(#EA3D05 50%, #fff 50%);
  border: 1px solid #EA3D05;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /* adjust below until you get closer */
  background: #EA3D05;
  mix-blend-mode: hue;
}
```

```html
<p>Original image</p>
<div class="box"></div>

<p>New image</p>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box" style="filter:invert(100%);"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a second filter to rotate your hue from blue to red

```
filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(170deg)
```

you can optionally add saturation after to optimize the look of the red against the black